# How to hide id and display their name's instead?

Tags: php

[image: Here's the example]

I don't how to hide the id of the running candidates which is `candid`, I can't remove in the value because it will handle the votes of the candidates I really need some help or any solution. I want that it will display the names in the preview.php and hide the id but don't know how?

Here's the code of plsvote.php:

```
value="<?php echo $rows['candid'] . "-" ."&nbsp". $rows['lastname'] .",". "&nbsp". $rows['firstname'] ?>"> <?php echo $rows['lastname'] ?>,
<?php echo $rows['firstname'] ?>

- <?php 
    echo $rows['party_name']?></option>
```

Here's the preview.php:

```
<?php
$resultasa = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candposition");
$resultasa->execute();
for($i=0; $rowasa = $resultasa->fetch(); $i++){
$exrxrxrx=$rowasa['pos_name'];

if ($exrxrxrx!='Error') {
?>
<h2 class="fs-title"><?php echo $exrxrxrx ?></h2>
//this is the part where I call the value and also the codes of my example image
<input type="hidden"  value="<?php echo explode("#", $_POST[$exrxrxrx])[0] ?>" name="votes[]" /><?php echo explode("#", $_POST[$exrxrxrx])[0] ?><br>
```

Comment: if possible wrap this with span like `<span class="cand-id">' . $rows['candid'] . '</span>'`

Comment: `$exrxrxrx` is the worst variable name I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data attrbute in HTML5 to store the id.

Example:

```
<span data-id="<?= $id?>"><?= $firstname?> <?= $lastname?></span>
```

Comment: should I put this on the value and replace ?